# OpenAM + two LDAP servers

Tags: ldap, liferay, openam

I'm a newbie in the LDAP + Liferay + OpenAM world, so I wonder if someone could point me in the right direction in a problem I have. In a real life environment, there are 2 LDAP servers, a OpenAM server and a Liferay application. What the customer needs is to authenticate users in Liferay against OpenAM, and OpenAM should use the LDAP servers. Problem is, the user exists only in one of the LDAP servers (it will be moved from one to the other in one point of the future). What the customer wants is:

1. Users must be able to authenticate independently of what LDAP contains the user.
2. The obtained token must be valid for both LDAP servers, as it will be used in a different service (I have no control over it) against only one of them to validate authentication.

As I said, I'm new to this world so, if the answer is too complex (I'm afraid it will be for me), maybe you could point me to books or docs that could resolve this scenario.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the previous answer states you should route all your authentication requests to the OpenAM server and let it validate the credentials against the right LDAP server. Using two different realms (one for each LDAP server) won't work in your case since that will require LifeRay to know where to find the user before hand. Also, sessions are linked to a specific realm.

There are multiple solutions to your problem. Here are just a couple:

## Option 1

If you have control over the authentication flow. That is, if your application uses a custom UI and communicates with OpenAM via REST, you could create two different authentication module instances under a single realm (let's say two instances of the DataStore authentication module) each one pointing to a different LDAP server.

Let's call this module instances DataStore1 and DataStore2. Your application can collect the user credentials (username and password) and submit them to DataStore1. If authentication succeeds the user is already logged in. If it fails, the application can try with DataStore2.

Of course this is not ideal since you'll be making two authentication requests per login instead of just one.

## Option 2

A better option (though more complicated to implement) would be creating a custom authentication module. This module can try authenticating the user against LDAP Server 1 and then try with LDAP Server 2 if the first authentication failed. Notice that with this option you don't need custom logic on the application side since it will only send a single authentication request to the OpenAM server. In fact, you can protect your application with an OpenAM Policy Agent.

Another advantage of this approach over Option 1 is that you can migrate your users behind the scenes assuming that the end goal is to migrate users from LDAP Server 1 to LDAP Server 2. If the first authentication succeeds your custom code could read the user entry from LDAP Server 1 and copy it over to LDAP Server 2.

Hope this helps you solve the problem.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thank you very much. I'll try these alternatives and post my experience with the configuration :)

Answer (score 1):

You should configure LifeRay to use OpenAM for all authentications and you can configure OpenAM to use both LDAP servers (use different realms).
Details for OpenAM configuration will be in the OpenAM documentation.